# How to reset MFA with powershell and test it?

Tags: powershell, reset, multi-factor-authentication

I'm looking for a way to reset the MFA for a specific user. Right now I'm using the command

```
  Reset-MsolStrongAuthenticationMethodbyUpn -UserPrincipalName $user
```

However I don't think this is working properly. Here is my code:

```
  Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred 
  $user = "user@test.com"
  Reset-MsolStrongAuthenticationMethodbyUpn -UserPrincipalName $user
```

Then, to check if the MFA was reset I do:

```
$userMFA = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user |select -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationUserDetails 
$userPhoneNumber = $userMFA.PhoneNumber
```

But the phone number is still there and isn't erased.
Am I testing this right? Maybe there is another way to check is the MFA was reseted, I'm just not another way to test it. Does anyone now if there is a better way to check if the code worked (through powershell or not)?